# How to use Sliding Activity and Fragment Activity in a single class?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragmentactivity, android-sliding

So I have an app where in one of the screens there is a sliding menu (jfeinstein's) and I also want to implement a tab view using fragments. For this I need to extend the FragmentActivity but I have already extended SlidingActivity and I can't extend more than one class. Is there a way to work around this so that I have both a sliding menu and a tab menu in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of extending the Activity you can integrate it, as listed in point 1 of the usage guidelines.

"You can wrap your Activities in a SlidingMenu by constructing it programmatically (`new SlidingMenu(Context context)`) and then calling `SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(Activity activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW | SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT)`. `SLIDING_WINDOW` will include the Title/ActionBar in the content section of the SlidingMenu, while `SLIDING_CONTENT` does not. You can check it out in the example app `AttachExample` Activity."

[- GitHub page, usage section](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

The SlidingMenu was written for a time when the navigation drawer pattern didn't have a native implementation in the SDK. There is one now: you can use the NavigationDrawer which is included in the v4 Support Library. There is a guide for that [here on the developer pages](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).